# Accessing Amazon with Guzzle gives 403 forbidden

Tags: symfony, curl, web-scraping, proxy, guzzle

I was trying to programmatically access the following url:

https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=garlic+press

```
$response = $client->get($url, ['proxy' => 'http://someproxy','timeout' => 10, 'cookies' => $jar]);
```

and I receive the following response:

[image]

It looks like my request is rejected by cloudfront.

Answer (score 0):

You should try setting your User-Agent headers to something sensible. It may be CloudFront refuses to serve content to unknown user agents.

Comment: Have you tried some additional headers like Referer, Cookie? Maybe the documentation will help: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html

Why aren't you using their API? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ProgrammingGuide.html